# iDRAC virtual console download hangs at 0%

Tags: drac

Occasionally, when attempting to launch a virtual console from the `.jnlp` file that I have downloaded from the iDRAC control panel, the Java applet will launch, attempt to download additional jars, but will hang at 0%.

I can't produce this problem at-will, but this seems to be the series of events whenever it *does* happen:

1. Download the `.jnlp` file from an iDRAC, and successfully launch virtual console.
2. Repeat successfully for several different iDRACs.
3. On some arbitrary attempt, the downloaded `.jnlp` file launches, but hangs at 0% forever.

Some notes:

- I have observed this happening on several iDRAC firmware versions in the 2.* range, but most recently on version `2.20.20.20`
- Centos 7.2
- OpenJDK version `1.8.0_71`
- Iced Tea Java browser plugin
- Chrome browser, version `49.0.2623.87`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like clearing the cache directory via...

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/*
```

...will allow me to successfully launch a virtual console.